# How do I create game matches with websockets in the backend (Nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, backend

I'm trying to make an online, turn based game, for phones, using Websockets in the backend. In this game, you'll be able to join a match, and play with 6 other people, but I'm not sure how to make this.

I know in socket.io there's something called "rooms" which I guess could be used. But will it be able to handle many different matches going on at the same time?

Is it possible/viable to do something like this using just one server?

PS: I'm using the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package, since Socket.io doesn't have an official integration with Flutter yet.

Comment: Your single server question depends upon hundreds of factors related to the number of users scale and load of your application, implementation of your application and the type of hardware and network deployed.  Not something we can answer here with no information and ultimately something that is only really evaluated with a prototype implementation and load testing.  It shouldn't be hard to service hundreds, perhaps thousands of simultaneous users with one server, even tens of thousands with the right design and deployment, but it also depends upon the design of your app.

Comment: This question needs to be a lot more specific.  There's just not really anything we can answer here.

Comment: Of course it depends on the design. A design solution is exactly what I’m looking for with this question. All I’m asking is if its possible to do it with Websockets with one server. I do not think of this as a solution for when the game have hundreds of thousand of players. But just something sustainable for small games.

Comment: Well, it's possible to do with one server up to some scale that depends upon all those other things.  You can use a plain webSocket connection or a socket.io connection (which uses a webSocket as the transport and just adds features on top of that).  Socket.io rooms are a very lightweight collection of live socket.io connections (they are literally just a Javascript object with a list of socket.io connections that are "in" that room) and a means of broadcasting to that subset of sockets.  It's useful and lightweight and would be simple to replicate yourself.

Comment: You could also use SSE (server sent events) for server -> client transmissions and http requests for client --> server transmissions.

Comment: Questions that amount to "How do I design this?" don't really work here and are usually considered off-topic.  Design choices like this are not something that can't be answered in a few paragraphs as they can involve lots of considerations.  If you intend for your app to still be live and get notifications when it's not the foreground app on the phone, then you may have other considerations too (like maybe you need to use the phone's native push solution) because for power management reasons you app may not be allowed to keep a long lasting connection when in the background.